# Why does the compiler accept an ambiguous variables definitions?

Tags: c++, g++, ambiguous

I have such pretty little code:

```
//example1
namespace 
{
    int a;
}

int a;

main()
{
    a++;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, g++ 4.6.1 compiler can't compile it and outputs an error:

```
./temp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./temp.cpp:10:5: error: reference to ‘a’ is ambiguous
./temp.cpp:6:5: error: candidates are: int a
./temp.cpp:2:9: error:                 int {anonymous}::a
```

It's all right!

But when I delete the reference to variable "**a**" within "**main**" function, the program is being compiled well:

```
//example2
namespace 
{
    int a;
}

int a;

main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

1) Why does the g++ compiler allows the definition of variable "**a**", when in such case it disallows the references to it?

2) Is it just the g++ compiler's feature, and no other compiler is able to compile such code (example2)?

3) Does the g++ compiler have corresponding flags to interpret such code (example2) as faulty?

Thanks a lot for everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example is valid because you can still access the global `a` from outside that translation unit.

The `a` in the anonymous namespace provides a definition for a variable that has internal linkage. The `a` at global namespace scope is a definition for a variable with external linkage. You can declare a `extern int a;` in a different translation unit and use it.

Comment: Really! :) I guess, in such variable's "a" usage, it should be placed to the end of source code...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "because there's nothing illegal about it". It's just using `a` in main that is wrong. If you use `::a` it will give you the global one (without the namespace).

And you can use `a` inside the namespace itself, e.g. we could have a function:

```
namespace {
   int a;

   int work_with_a()
   {
      a += 2;
      return a;
   }

}


int a;

int main()
{
   ::a++;

   int b = work_with_a();

   cout << ::a + b; 
}
```

Comment: How can I use "a" variable from anonymous namespace? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just because you can't reference the `a` in the anonymous namespace from `main` doesn't mean the code is invalid.

The `a` in the anonymous namespace can still be referenced from within the anonymous namespace.

The global `a` can be referenced from everywhere (you'd have to use `::a` in `main` to remove the ambiguity).